Is there a formula for calculating the strength of a suction?
Let’s say I have a plunger and I know the area of where it suctions, the volume of the vacuum, and assuming it had been completely sealed and has 100% vacuum (not likely!)
Could I figure out how much weight it could hold up?
Any other measurements that would need to be known is also ok.
I know what I am asking is very vague, but is there some kind if formula that describes and predicts how ‘strong’ the suction will be?

Calculating the force of suction is as simple as calculating the net force on the object and seeing how things balance out. There are two forces acting on the plunger: air pressure and the normal force of the wall that it is stuck to (i.e. the wall pushes back). If there is perfect vacuum on one side, then all of the air pressure force is from the outside, and this is the force of suction. So the force of suction is simply $PA$, where $P$ is the ambient pressure and $A$ is the area.
If you consider plungers with different shapes, then you might rightly ask what 'area' should mean here. Suction is the upward force due to air pressure, so we should only consider area projected onto the plane that the plunger is stuck to. So in all three examples pictured below, the suction force will be the same. The inward forces pictured in case 2 don't contribute to the suction force.


Very good answer- upvoted!
